# Get first item matching condition in large SharePoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

So I have a SP list with about 100k items (voucher codes) in it.
Each of them has columns for State (Active/Used), Value (10,20,30) Group (Normal, Special) and Code (random alphanumeric). Each of the columns are indexed

I can't use CAML to get the next active code for a certain group and value, because each of the criteria would return > 5k items (list view threshold).

So what would be the most efficient way to retrieve the next code?
As the list is continuously growing, loading all items with SPListItemCollectionPosition is not really an option. Isn't there a better way?
It should work for onprem, as well as spOnline

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your Code is a progressive number, increasing at any new entered item, you have 2 options:

1. Create a service List that you can name something like CodeCounter, here you store the last created Code in a column. Create a workflow in main list, starting at item creation. This workflow will read the last created Code from service list, then update it to Code+1 and in parallel manages the update (optional) of main code in main list
2. use an event handler (farm solution, here the query surely works better)

Comment: Hi, so the codes are random alphanumeric digits, and it should run in SPO, so no farm solutions either.

Comment: Hi, let me understand better: if the code is random, it means it is automatically generated? Basing on which criteria or algorithm do you expect the next code is generated?

Comment: Codes are random and added to the list once per week. So its continuously growing. What I want to do is get the next active code from that list. At some point in time there will be thousands of used codes (ID 1...n) and active codes (n+1 .... z). Going through all items will then be less effective.

Comment: If codes are random, the only way you can guess the next code is to know how the algorithm that creates the code works. Depending by algorithm you are using, this might be even not possible (for instance, the algorithm might be based on date and time of generation or similar)